# transformations.switchMap works only once or possibly not at all

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

I am looking for some help with transformations.switchMap. I somehow can't get it to work and start to wonder if I actually understand things correctly.

Based on my understanding the first parameter is like a trigger, whenever it's values changes the, second parameter/function will be mapped/called to return a new/modified liveData object.
In my case I have:

```
#MainActivity
viewModel.repository.items.observe(requireActivity(), Observer { weight -> weight?.let { adapter!!.setItems(it) } })

#ViewModel
lateinit var items: LiveData<List<Weight>>      # Used in my RecyclerView
var filterChanged = MutableLiveData<Long>(0L)   # The "trigger" value

override fun init() {
    super.init()
    items = Transformations.switchMap(filterChanged) {repository.getItems(0L, filterEnd)}
}
```

repository.getItems() returns a live data object filtered by filterEnd (SQL ...where timestamp <= filterEnd), with timestamp being a date in numerical representation.

This works! But only once, during initialisation of the Fragment. Once the fragment has initialised I can change the filterChanged trigger variable as often as I want,
the repository.getItems() function does not get called a second time (applying an updated value for filterEnd).

It requires start/stop of a secondary activity (settings or about) which will recreate my viewModel to update the filter value.

I saw several ways of crafting the Transformations.switchMap statement, using lambdas, one parameter or two, etc., but I either couldn't get them to compile or they didn't do what I expected.

Now, have I understood correctly how this is supposed to work? Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Edit: Added the repository section to clarify things:

```
    #Repository
    items = getItems(filterStart, filterEnd) # This is where I enter from the ViewModel

    // This function redirects to the actual dao functions, 
    fun getItems(filterStart: Long, filterEnd: Long): LiveData<List<Weight>> {
            Log.d("Repository ", "getItems: $filterStart, $filterEnd")
            if ((filterStart != 0L) && (filterEnd == 0L)) return dao.getItemsGreaterThan(filterStart)
            else if ((filterStart == 0L) && (filterEnd != 0L)) return dao.getItemsLessThan(filterEnd)
            else if ((filterStart != 0L) && (filterEnd != 0L)) return dao.getItemsRange(filterStart, filterEnd)
            else return dao.getItems()
    }
```

At one point I simplified things and called the dao functions directly, like so:

```
items = dao.getItemsLessThan(filterEnd)
```

Even bypassed the repository allt ogether and called the respective dao function directly from the ViewModel, but that didn't make any difference either.
And then there are the corresponding dao functions, like the below:

```
@Query("SELECT * from weight WHERE timestamp >=:start ORDER BY timestamp DESC")
abstract fun getItemsGreaterThan(start: Long): LiveData<List<Weight>>
```

Comment: If is possible add your repository code, to see the logic.

Comment: Happy to, I updated the original post to show the repository section.

Comment: Make `filterChanged` into `val`

Comment: Well, that didn't help either, but your question made me stumble over my brain fart :-)
The observer in MainActivity is observing repository.items, but my switchmap is on ViewModel.item. Well, clearly two different variables. Changing the observer to viewModel.items solved the issue immediately.
Thanks for asking the question and driving this to a conclusion, this has been bugging me for quite a while.